# SAS Proc report style

Tags: sas, report, proc

I am writing a code to display following records with proc report. I want to highlight the maximum number from each row with red color. I have tried the code but its highlighting different values. Please provide the correction in following code to display values highlighted correctly.

```
    data records;
    input a1 a2 a3 a4 a5;
    cards;
    37 95 80 52 85 
    94 .  7  10 14 
    64 5  71 14 92 
    .  55 38 .  46 
    ;
    run;

    proc report data=records nowd;
    column a1 a2 a3 a4 a5;
    define a1/display;
    define a2/display;
    define a3/display;
    define a4/display;
    define a5/display;

    compute a1;
    if a1=Max(a1,a2,a3,a4,a5) then call define('a1','style','style={foreground=white background=red}');
    endcomp;
    compute a2;
    if a2=Max(a1,a2,a3,a4,a5) then call define('a2','style','style={foreground=white background=red}');
    endcomp;
    compute a3;
    if a3=max(a1,a2,a3,a4,a5) then call define('a3','style','style={foreground=white background=red}');
    endcomp;
    compute a4;
    if a4=max(a1,a2,a3,a4,a5) then call define('a4','style','style={foreground=white background=red}');
    endcomp; 
    compute a5;
    if a5=max(a1,a2,a3,a4,a5) then call define('a5','style','style={foreground=white background=red}');
    endcomp; 
    run;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as i know, if you use a compute statement, the order is important. So if you use compute a1, only a1 has a value at that time, compute a2 means that only a1 and a2 have a value, and so on...

So you must use your last column for a compute statement, then all columns have values and the result should be ok.

Found this on [Sas page](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/proc/61895/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a002473626.htm):

> Note:   The position of a computed variable is important. PROC REPORT assigns values to the columns in a row of a report from left to right. Consequently, you cannot base the calculation of a computed variable on any variable that appears to its right in the report

So try it this way, it worked for me:

```
proc report data=records nowd;
column a1 a2 a3 a4 a5;
define a1/display;
define a2/display;
define a3/display;
define a4/display;
define a5/display; 

compute a5;
if a1=Max(a1,a2,a3,a4,a5) then call define('a1','style','style={foreground=white background=red}');
if a2=Max(a1,a2,a3,a4,a5) then call define('a2','style','style={foreground=white background=red}');
if a3=max(a1,a2,a3,a4,a5) then call define('a3','style','style={foreground=white background=red}');
if a4=max(a1,a2,a3,a4,a5) then call define('a4','style','style={foreground=white background=red}');
if a5=max(a1,a2,a3,a4,a5) then call define('a5','style','style={foreground=white background=red}');
endcomp; 
run;
```

[image]